# Angular redirect a url to the main page

Tags: angular, redirect

I am totally new to Angular and I need to redirect a url to the main page. I tried modifying the route as below but I do not see any redirection.

```
  import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

  export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => 
  import('./modules/documents/documents.module').then(m => 
  m.DocumentsModule) },
  { path: '', component: AppComponent },
  { path: '**accessibility/', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  // Fallback when no prior route is matched
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your main component, too. Like this:

```
 { path: 'main', component: MainComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }.
```

The `redirectTo` value must be the "path" name of the component you wanna redirect.

Comment: shoud I keep this?  { path: '*/accessibility', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' }. <--THIS ONE

Comment: It depends on what you wanna expect. If you wanna redirect all urls with **accessibility** at the end of the url you should do it like this: `**accessibility/`

Comment: I have put the new code in this post, can you see it? Unfortunately not working yet

Comment: My issue... a typo `**/accessibility`. But tell me: What does not work? All routes, or only redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Write your routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

Or, Write a function to redirect from a component

```
redirectPage(){
       window.location.href="../home"
}
```